# Existence of derivative of a function (as difference of no differentiable functions)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If I have to prove that $f(x)=h(x)+g(x)=\arcsin{x}+\arccos{x}$ is constant I have thought to use the fact that if $f'(x)=0$ in its domain than the function is constant.

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=0$, so I have done.

**My doubt:** $h$ and $g$ have not derivative in $x=1$, this is also for f?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ and constant on $(-1,1)$, the function $f$ is constant on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: this ok! but my question is: f is differentiable oin x=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You consider the functions $\arcsin, \arccos :[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$. You do not tell us which range they have, so let us assume that we take the principal values $\arcsin :[-1,1] \to [-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2]$ and $\arccos :[-1,1] \to [0, \pi]$.

In principle your doubt is justified: If you have two functions $g, h$ which are not differentiable in a point $x_0$ of their domain, then there is no reason why the sum $f = g + h$ should be differentiable in $x_0$. Nevertheless it may be differentiable in $x_0$ coincidentally, for example if $h = -g$.

So you should not try to show that $f = \arcsin + \arccos$ is differentiable in $\pm 1$ by considering the two summands separately. You know that  $f'(x)$ exists on $(-1,1)$ and has the value $0$, thus $f \mid_{(-1,1)}$ is constant with value
$$ f(0) = \arcsin(0) + \arccos(0) = 0 + \frac \pi 2 = \frac \pi 2 .$$
Since $f$ is continuous, we conclude that $f$ is constant on $[-1,1]$ with value $\frac \pi 2$.

Alternatively you can directly compute
$$f(1) = \arcsin(1) + \arccos(1) = \frac \pi 2 + 0 = \frac \pi 2 ,$$
$$f(-1) = \arcsin(-1) + \arccos(-1) = -\frac \pi 2 + \pi  = \frac \pi 2.$$

This answers your question: $f$ is differentiable in $\pm 1$ simply because it is constant.

Comment: Ok so to sum up: I know that it is continuous in (-1,1), then I prove that it is constant in (-1,1) but also in $\pm 1$ by continuity and so since here it is constant then it will be differentiable also in $x=\pm 1$, right?

Comment: @jin Essentially correct. You know that it is **continuous on $[-1,1]$** and **differentiable on $(-1,1)$** with derivative $0$, thus it is constant on $(-1,1)$ and by continuity constant on all of $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot